# Translation Server-side vs. Client-side when having the same locales files

Tags: api, api-design, internationalization, client-side

I'm currently working on a Turborepo project (monorepo architecture) and I have managed t share my locales files to both back-end and front-end parts.
This means I share the exact same keys across those 2.

When coming to internationalization, I've asked myself few questions and came to these conclusions:

- Server sending back translation keys is great since my applications share them, but adding a new key / modifying it is quite a labor for what it is (or am I overkilling it?)
- Server sending back full translated messages is also great because it makes the client-side kind of a dumb renderer. Thing is, the server should keep in mind the user's language. What if there is no language ? (e.g. Wrong Credentials error -> the user is not connected, therefore I have no source of truth regarding its language)
- Client-side translation based on HttpCodes sent back by the server and associate a translation on the go, ~meh~.

What is considered "the best practice"?

Comment: I'm confused by your last two bullet points. What do you mean by "Wrong Credentials"

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Client-side translation of HttpCodes". How does the HTTP protocol matter to text that is visible to an end user?